# Can I use the Hat of Disguise to make layered illsions?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

Can I use the hat to make Multiple effects that are layered? I.E. I look like a Ogre over looking like a goblin, over looking like my self using a disguise kit with the +10 to Disguise to just not look like me?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

> A Hat of Disguise allows its wearer to alter her appearance as with a
> *disguise self* spell.

You could stack several *Disguise Self* spells to achieve the desired "layered" effect, as per the rules:

> Combining Magical Effects->Stacking Effects->Same Effect with Differing Results
>
> The same spell can sometimes produce varying effects
> if applied to the same recipient more than once. Usually the last
> spell in the series trumps the others. None of the previous spells are
> actually removed or dispelled, but their effects become irrelevant
> while the final spell in the series lasts.

BUT, the *Hat of Disguise* doesn't let you cast *Disguise Self* at will, it only allows you to alter your appearance as with that spell, so, there is only a single magical effect active on you, that gets modified each time you use the item. Therefore there is nothing to stack, or to layer.

You could stack the *Hat of Disguise* with a casting of *Disguise Self* though.